# Move agents to a node based on a condition in Netlogo

Tags: networking, netlogo, agent

I would like to create a network in Netlogo, put 3 agents on the first node of the network and make them move to a connected node.

Specifically I'd like the agents choose the node to move to based on a probability. If there is no agent on a connected node, choose it with *p = 0.5*, if **there is** an agent on the node choose it with *p = 0.7*. So if - for example - the starting node has two neighbouring nodes and one of them has an other agent on it, it should be chosen with a higher probability.

I've managed to create the network and move the agents randomly, but I can't figure out how to make an agent "know" if there is an other agent on a node and set the probabilities based on this condition.

```
breed [nodes node]
breed [walkers walker]

walkers-own [location ]

to setup
  clear-all
  set-default-shape nodes "circle"
  create-nodes 18 [set color white]
  ask nodes [ create-link-with one-of other nodes ]
  layout-circle nodes 10
  create-walkers 3 [
    set location node 1
    move-to location
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask walkers [
    let new-location one-of [link-neighbors] of location ;; choose a new location randomly
    move-to new-location
    set location new-location
  ]
  tick
end
```

I thought of making an `occupied?` variable and update it based on the position of the agents, but it would be a `nodes-own` variable, which I couldn't connect to the agents (`walkers`).

I am new to Netlogo and not aware of all the possibilities and limitations, so it is possible I am looking at this problem all wrong. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sielu,  a couple of points.

First,  creating a link will fail silently if there is already a link between those two nodes.  The result is that some of your nodes will end up with only one neighbor. If that's not ok, you need to work on your link creation logic.

Second, it may not be obvious, but some nodes will end up with more than two links,
so a walker may have many different paths to choose from.

Third, a node may have more than one occupant. For example, all the other walkers might be on it.

Given all that, I'm going to assume that what you're asking for is for each walker to start looking at its linked-nodes,  set some probability based on the occupancy of the target node, select a random number, and if it's below that probability move to that node and stop looking at other possible moves. If the random number is above that probability, however, then the walker should forget about that link and move on to considering the next one.  If all links fail their separate tests, the walker doesn't move.

The code below implements that.  It got kind of long and messy. Here's the key features.

- I added a verbose? switch that turns on or off printing out details for debugging
  and it asks the user whether to be verbose or not on each setup.   If you hit
  go once ( not forever ) you can see what got set and if its what you wanted.
- I added a count-of-walkers to each node, versus a true/false occupancy? switch
- I added a sequence number ( like "who" ) to each watcher to make the output
  read more sensibly
- the GO step makes a LIST of nodes that are link-neighbors to the node the watcher
  is standing on.    Then it sorts the list into the order you want to examine
  them.  ( I used a list because you might care what order they are looked at, and
  agent sets are randomly ordered. ) I sorted them into ascending order by the
  the occupancy counts, so it will first look at the unoccupied nodes, then the 
  occupied ones, up to the most occupied ones.
- Then it goes through that list, deciding whether to move to that node or not.
  Once it does decide to move, it stops looking at the list, so some of the nodes
  will not even be considered for a move.
- You can see the section where probabilities are set depending on the occupancy
  count of the node.  I used your 0.5 and 0.7 probabilities and added a 0.9 
  probability if there are 2 or more watchers on the target node.
- The code has a lot of comments,and if you set verbose? to true,  you can 
  examine how each watcher considers ( or doesn't) each link and makes its
  decision to move or not.

The code runs and looks ok, so far as I can tell what it is you want. Ask me
questions if it's not clear what I did.

```
breed [nodes node]
breed [walkers walker]

walkers-own [location seqnum ]  ;; seqqnum is like who but for the walkers

nodes-own[ count-of-walkers ]    ;; ADDED

globals [verbose?]

to setup
  clear-all
  set verbose? false                     ;; if true, prints a lot for debugging purposes
  if user-yes-or-no? "Print debugging info on each step?" [set verbose? true]

  set-default-shape nodes "circle"
  create-nodes 18 [set color white]
  ask nodes [ create-link-with one-of other nodes ]
  layout-circle nodes 10
  let seq 1               ;; start of sequence numbers for walkers
  create-walkers 3 [
    set size 3
    set color red
    set location node 1
    set seqnum seq set seq seq + 1  ;; assign the sequence number
    move-to location
    ask location [ set count-of-walkers count-of-walkers + 1 ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if verbose? [print "    ================================== starting the go loop"]
  ask walkers [

    let candidate-set []  ;; this will be an agent set of neighboring linked nodes

    ask location [set candidate-set link-neighbors ]  ;; ask my node to find its neighbors

    ;; sort the neighbors into some order and make a list of them
    ;; the next line sorts them into ascending order by occupancy ( lowest first )
    ;; we will consider a move to each one in that order

    let candidate-list sort-on [count-of-walkers] candidate-set  

    if verbose? [
     type "walker " type seqnum
     type " is checking out these neighbors: " print candidate-list
    ]

    ;;     Examine each neighbor and decide whether to move there based on probabilities
    ;;     if we find a place to move we like  terminate processing the list
    ;;     otherwise, remove that candidate neighbor from the list
    ;;     and keep doing that until the list is empty
    ;;  

    while [length candidate-list > 0 ]  [        ;; while we haven't decided to move yet


        ;; pop the first item off the list  
        let candidate first candidate-list            ;; pull the first item
        set candidate-list but-first candidate-list   ;; and remove it from the list

      ;; decide what probability to use for considering THIS move
       let prob-of-move 0  ;; a default value
       let occupant-count [ count-of-walkers ] of candidate ;; count walkers on that node

       if occupant-count = 0 [ set prob-of-move 0.5 ]
       if occupant-count = 1 [ set prob-of-move 0.7 ]
       if occupant-count > 1 [ set prob-of-move 0.9 ]

      if verbose? [
       type " ... candidate " type candidate
       type " has this many walkers " type [count-of-walkers] of candidate
       type " so set probability of move to " print prob-of-move
      ]

      ;; make a decision to move or not based on that probability
        if-else random-float 1 < prob-of-move [
        if verbose? [type  " ......moving to " print candidate]
        ;;let new-location candidate
        set candidate-list []  ;; make the list empty so this WHILE loop will exit
        move-to candidate      ;; move the walker on the display

        ;; update the counts of walkers on each affected node
        ask candidate [ set count-of-walkers count-of-walkers + 1 ]
        ask location  [ set count-of-walkers count-of-walkers - 1 ]

        ;; finally, tell the walker where it is now
        set location candidate

      ]
      [if verbose? [ print " ..... was not selected for a move to this node"]]

    ]

    if verbose? [ print " ..............done with processing walkers for this tick"]

    ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: By the way, be careful modifying the WHILE loop.  Be sure that the list gets set to [] somewhere, which is the stopping condition, or it will "runaway" forever.